# I can't use NumberFormatExeption. The program should continue even if the user input a string or non-number

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch, numberformatexception, try-catch-finally

## Guessing the number

```
import java.util.*;

public class LabExer5A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
        Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 50");
        int JPS_Guess = Input.nextInt();
        int JPS_CorrectNum = 25;
        int JPS_NextGuess;  
    do
    {
    try
    {
            if (JPS_Guess == JPS_CorrectNum)
            {
                System.out.println("You got it in ");
            }
            else if (JPS_Guess < JPS_CorrectNum && JPS_Guess >= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
                JPS_NextGuess = Input.nextInt();
                JPS_Guess = JPS_NextGuess;
            }
            else if (JPS_Guess > JPS_CorrectNum && JPS_Guess <= 50)
            {
                System.out.println("Too High. Try again.");
                JPS_NextGuess = Input.nextInt();
                JPS_Guess = JPS_NextGuess;
            }
            else if(JPS_Guess < 1 || JPS_Guess > 50)
            {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
    }
         catch(InputMismatchException e) 
         {
            System.out.println("Invalid value. Please enter a number between 1 and 50: ");
            JPS_NextGuess = Input.nextInt();
            JPS_Guess = JPS_NextGuess;
         }   
          catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
         {
            System.out.println("Error - Enter Numerical Values Only");
            JPS_NextGuess = Input.nextInt();
            JPS_Guess = JPS_NextGuess;
         }  
    }
    while (JPS_Guess != JPS_CorrectNum);//will rerun the program until the user guess the correct number   
}
}
```

}

}

I'm not sure where I made the mistake. Either the use of the throw catch or maybe because of the way I rerun the program. I'm pretty new to using exception and try-catch Please help and be kind. Thank you.

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt()` actually throws InputMismatchException when you input other data type so you can directly use the catch for InputMismatchException and you should add `Input.next()` so that the scanner will take in the non integer input

Another thing is that `Input.nextInt()` should always be inside the try/catch. In your code, the exception will not be catched for the first input and after you input any wrong value.

```
 catch(InputMismatchException e) 
         {
            System.out.println("Invalid value. Please enter a number between 1 and 50: ");
            JPS_NextGuess = Input.nextInt();
            JPS_Guess = JPS_NextGuess;
         }
```

I have modified your code to be simpler. I suggest you use boolean to keep track of whether the number is guessed so you don't have to interchange the guess. Also, good indentation formatting helps reading.

```
import java.util.*;

public class LabExer5A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 50");
        int JPS_CorrectNum=25;
        boolean isGuessed=false;  
        do
        {
            try
            {
                int JPS_Guess = Input.nextInt();
                if (JPS_Guess == JPS_CorrectNum)
                {
                    System.out.println("You got it in ");
                    isGuessed=true;
                }
                else if (JPS_Guess < JPS_CorrectNum && JPS_Guess >= 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
                }
                else if (JPS_Guess > JPS_CorrectNum && JPS_Guess <= 50)
                {
                    System.out.println("Too High. Try again.");
                }
                else if(JPS_Guess < 1 || JPS_Guess > 50)
                {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid value. Please enter a number between 1 and 50: ");
                Input.next();
            }   
        }
        while (!isGuessed);//will rerun the program until the user guess the correct number   
    }
}
```